# Inner Listener & Timer for Football Game program

Tags: java, swing, timer, inner-classes, listeners

I would like to know how I can apply a Timer and all my listeners as inner classes. I'm still confused about inner classes so can someone explain and how I can apply it to my own program, that would be much appreciated. I just learned timer but I'm not sure where and how to set it. I would like to set for 60 seconds.

here is my code:

```
package runningback;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener
{
    JLabel text = new JLabel("Touchdowns: ");
    JLabel text2 = new JLabel("Tackles: ");
    JLabel touchdownsLbl;
    JLabel tacklesLbl;
    JButton movingButton = new JButton("key code");
    JButton startBtn = new JButton("Start");
    JLabel background=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("playground.png"));
    JLabel rb=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("rb.png"));
    JLabel tackler=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("tackler.png"));
     int x =0;
     int y = 10;
     int touchdowns;
     int tackles;
     Player mainPlayer;
public MainPanel()
{
        mainPlayer = new Player();
        touchdowns = 0;
        tackles = 0;
        touchdownsLbl = new JLabel(Integer.toString(touchdowns));
        tacklesLbl = new JLabel(Integer.toString(tackles));

        setLayout(null);
        //setBackground(Color.pink);
        add(text);
        add(text2);
        add(touchdownsLbl);
        add(tacklesLbl);
        text.setBounds(new Rectangle(350, 20, 350, 30));
        text2.setBounds(new Rectangle(450, 20, 350, 30));
        touchdownsLbl.setBounds(new Rectangle(435, 20, 350, 30));
        tacklesLbl.setBounds(new Rectangle(505, 20, 350, 30));
        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
        add(rb);
        add(background);
        background.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 94, 624, 416));

        rb.setBounds(new Rectangle(mainPlayer.x, mainPlayer.y, 50, 44));
        //add(movingButton);
        startBtn.setBounds(new Rectangle(250, 20, 80, 30));
        add(startBtn);
        startBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                //System.out.println("Button Pressed");
                gameReset();
            } 
        });
    //---------------------TIMER------------------------------
        int delay = 1000; // milliseconds
        tim = new Timer(delay,this);

        tim.start(); // starts the timer
        //---------------------TIMER------------------------------
        tim.setDelay(200);  // sets a new delay
        tim.stop();  // stops the timer // stops the timer
    }

      }
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) 
{
//System.out.println("Key pressed");
int kk = evt.getKeyCode();
if(kk ==  evt.VK_LEFT) {mainPlayer.x=mainPlayer.x-mainPlayer.speed;}
if(kk ==  evt.VK_RIGHT) {mainPlayer.x=mainPlayer.x+mainPlayer.speed;}
if(kk ==  evt.VK_UP) {mainPlayer.y=mainPlayer.y-mainPlayer.speed;}
if(kk ==  evt.VK_DOWN) {mainPlayer.y=mainPlayer.y+mainPlayer.speed;}
update();
//movingButton.setText(""+evt.getKeyCode()+","+evt.getKeyChar());
//movingButton.setBounds(new Rectangle(x,y,80,30));   
}

void update(){
rb.setBounds(new Rectangle(mainPlayer.x, mainPlayer.y, 50, 44));
}

 void gameReset(){
   mainPlayer.x = 30;
   mainPlayer.y = 280;
   update();
}
 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {  }
 public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {  }
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    //System.out.println("Painting");
    super.paintComponent(g);
    requestFocusInWindow();
}

  @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(624, 500);
}

}
```

Comment: You're already using "inner" classes above in some of your ActionListeners -- so please specify as much as possible what it is that exactly is confusing you. The better we understand the question, usually the better the answer. Myself, I'm somewhat confused as to why you're calling `requestFocusInWindow();` inside of a paintComponent method. That looks like a dangerous thing to do, and I'm not sure when you'd ever want that functionality.

Comment: Also, I don't see any Timer code above, so please clarify what you mean by this. Are you referring to a Swing Timer (javax.swing.Timer) instance?

Comment: I figured out my inner classes and added a timer.

           int delay = 1000; // milliseconds
            tim = new Timer(delay,this); 
            tim.start(); // starts the timer
            tim.setDelay(200);  // sets a new delay
            tim.stop();  // stops the timer // stops the timer

Answer (score 3):

```
public class MainPanel {
    // setting timer
    public void startTimer(double delay){
        long milisecond = 1000l;
        Timer t = new Timer((int) (delay*milisecond), new TimerListener());
        t.setInitialDelay((int) (delay*milisecond));
        t.start();
    }

    // inner classes
    public class TimerListener implements ActionListener{...}
    public class KeyListener extends KeyAdapter{...}
}
```

read more on [inner classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html).

read more on [timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)